# MQTT implementation in Android App

Tags: android, mqtt

I just have read about MQTT protocol and wanted to try out a PoT/PoC. I would like to know the steps that I should take up to start with development of an Android App - to transfer raw data that’s captured during the journey of a driver in a car from OBD to the back end and then process it at server end and send information to an android app.

So what are the requirements and set-up I would need at server OBD and at android client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and I don't know the first thing about how the onboard monitoring tools of vehicles operate so I'll just write what I know about setting up an MQTT communication channel between a server (.Net or Java) and the Android client.

If you want  to setup some sort of MQTT communication channel between your server and the android app, you should start by

1. Setting up the server: Install ActiveMQ and enable MQTT protocol on the machine you'll be hosting it on(http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html). There are other queuing technologies out there supporting this protocol as well so you're not limited to ActiveMQ but it's free and very configurable. Additionally, have a look at RabbitMQ since it also supports MQTT (http://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html) and try googling and reading pros and cons of these queues. As a disclaimer, I've only used ActiveMQ and Solace (extremely expensive middleware solution) so can't say anything negative/positive about RabbitMQ or any other queuing technologies. Just make sure whatever you choose supports guaranteed delivery and message persistence in case you need them.
2. Write your server code: From what I gather, you want your server to be a listener in most cases but also to be able to publish to a queue so that your app(s) can receive server communications. What you probably should do is to use at least 2 topics for this purpose. One for sending data from the Android phone to your server and one for receiving data on the Android (sent from the server). Depending on the programming language of your server, pick the correct drivers and work with them. All of them will support both subscribe and publish but not all will support MQTT so be sure to check this.
3. Write your client: To enable and work with MQTT in Android, you can start by reading this (http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/android-javadoc/index.html). There are examples in the `paho` source code that will guide you through setting up the queue and subscribing and publishing to it.